# Convert String from JSON to UIImage

Tags: ios, json, string, swift, uiimage

I'm receiving some JSON data from a webservice, which includes an image represented as a Sting. 
**How can I convert this string into an image?**

The JSON data is in an `NSDictionary`, and the Image data is the Object form the "`Content`"-key:

```
if let newBannerContentString = newBanner.objectForKey("Content") as? String {
    let someImage = UIImage(contentsOfFile: newBannerContentString)
}
```

This returns `nil` to someImage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If string is base64 encoded you could create `NSData` from that string and image from that data.

```
if let newBannerContentString = newBanner.objectForKey("Content") as? String {
    let data = NSData(base64EncodedString: newBannerContentString, options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions.IgnoreUnknownCharacters);
    let someImage = UIImage(data: data!);
}
```